# How to Incrementally Change Coordinates in PSTricks

Tags: xetex, pstricks, animations

I want to animate this document. Basically I want to change the value of `\X` from 6 to 3.7.

Below is the image and the code for reference

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl,multido,fp}

\FPset\Width{6.00}% paper width
\FPset\Height{4.00}% paper height

% \FPset\Step{0.50}% interline skip
% \FPeval\Lines{round(Height/Step-1:0)}% number of lines

\def\X{3.7}% abscissa of the top point
\def\Y{0}% ordinate of the right point

\psset
{
    PointName=none,
    PointSymbol=none,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](\Width,\Height)
        \pstGeonode(0,0){BottomLeft}(\Width,\Height){TopRight}(\X,\Height){Top}(\Width,\Y){Right}
        \pstOrtSym{Top}{Right}{TopRight}
        \pspolygon[dimen=inner](BottomLeft)(BottomLeft|Top)(Top)(Right)(TopRight|BottomLeft)    
        % \multips(\Step,\Step)(0,\Step){\Lines}{\psline[linewidth=3pt](!\Width\space 1 sub 0)}
        \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,linestyle=none](Top)(TopRight)(Right)
        \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,linejoin=1](Top)(TopRight')(Right)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Got it!

```tex
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl,multido,fp}

\FPset\Width{6.00}
\FPset\Height{4.00}


\psset
{
    PointName=none,
    PointSymbol=none,
}

\def\Picture#1#2{%
\def\X{#1}\def\Y{#2}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=tru](\Width,\Height)
        \pstGeonode(0,0){BottomLeft}(\Width,\Height){TopRight}(\X,\Height){Top}(\Width,\Y){Right}
        \pstOrtSym{Top}{Right}{TopRight}
        \pspolygon[dimen=inner](BottomLeft)(BottomLeft|Top)(Top)(Right)(TopRight|BottomLeft)    
        \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,linestyle=none](Top)(TopRight)(Right)
        \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,linejoin=1](Top)(TopRight')(Right)
\end{pspicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\multido{\nx=\Width+-0.1}{24}{\Picture{\nx}{0}}
\FPeval\Start{round(Width+14*(-0.25):2)}%
\end{document}
```